# Передача данных из Javascript в Razor

Tags: javascript, razor

Здравствуйте! Есть Razor-страница, на которой работает следующий JQuery-скрипт:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('tr').click(function () {        
    id = $(this).attr('id');
    $.soap({
        url: "http://localhost:8123/C_M_Service/",
        method: "OrdersByPassport",
        SOAPAction: "http://localhost:8123/C_M_Service/OrdersByPassport",           
        soap11: true,
        data: '<OrdersByPassport xmlns="http://C_M_Service">\
  <passport>'+id+'</passport>\
</OrdersByPassport>',
        error: function (soapresponse) {
            alert("Oh no is error: " + soapresponse.toString());
        },
        success: function (result) {                
            alert("OK " + result);
        }
    });
});
});
```

В случае его успешного выполнения в переменной `result` возвращаются запрашиваемые данные. Можно ли как-то работать с этими данными в коде Razor веб-страницы?

Попробовал обратиться к ответу так:

```
string data = "";
      HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create("http://localhost:8123/C_M_Service");         
      HttpWebResponse resp = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();
      Stream r_stream = resp.GetResponseStream();
      Encoding encode = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-8");
      StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(r_stream, encode);
      char [] read = new char [256];
      int count = reader.Read(read, 0, 256);
      while (count > 0)
      {
          string str = new string(read, 0, count);
          count = reader.Read(read, 0, 256);
          data = data + str;
      }
```

Comment: а что подразумевается под работой?

Comment: Мне нужно иметь возможность обратиться к  этим данным из Razor-кода.

Comment: Что Вы понимаете под обратится/работать?  Razor если обобщенно то это разметка страницы. Добавте конкретики в вопрос: что надо конкретно, что не получается.

Comment: Хочу сделать что-то вроде этого: @{My_type my_var = My_func(result);}.

Comment: Сами же эти данные на сервер не попадут. Делай HTTPPost на сервер, а данные передавай как параметр контроллера в MVC.

Comment: Здесь речь вообще не идёт о контроллере. Всё подразумевается в рамках одной страницы. Скрипт делает запрос и получает ответ. Мне нужно обработать ответ, полученный скриптом страницы, в Razor-коде этой же страницы.

Comment: а что мешает это сделать на сервере?! у Вас есть действие которое возвращает данные, а почему серверу не вернуть частичное представление?! т.е. Вы делаете запрос а в ответ получаете html разметку и заменяете её на текущей странице. в чем проблема то?! посмотрите здесь: http://metanit.com/sharp/mvc5/10.3.php Вы хотите что то подобное?!

Comment: В ответ на мой запрос приходит сообщение SOAP, а не разметка.

Comment: Razor код на сервере, а твой скрипт на клиенте и получает ответ на клиент.

Comment: @cpp_user в этом случае мы теряем распределенную обработку. все запросы проходят через сервер. а в исходном коде все запросы к soap работали с клиента на прямую.

Answer (score 1):

Если использование Razor вам необходимо для работы с html шаблонами, то вы можете воспользоваться шаблонизаторами на стороне клиента на javascript.

Например, вот [этим](http://olado.github.io/doT/index.html).

Привет вызова:

```
var tmpl = "{{~it.array :value:index}}" +
    "<div>{{=value}}!</div>" +
"{{~}}";

var tempFn = doT.template(tmpl);

var resultText = tempFn({"array":["banana","apple","orange"]});

//resultText: <div>banana!</div><div>apple!</div><div>orange!</div>
```

Comment: Я правильно понимаю: вы предлагаете мне генерировать разметку с учётом полученных данных из Javascript-кода?

Comment: генерировать html код на клиенте. Шаблон хранить там же или подтягивать его с сервера.

Comment: Решение хорошо маштабируется, так как всю работу мы переноси на клиента. Разгружая сервер от работы шаблонизатора Razor

Comment: Ситуация такова, что мне необходимо обрабатывать полученные данные с помощью кода, который написан на C#. Соответственно, вызвать его можно из Razor-кода. Хотя возможно это не лучший вариант, но на данный момент это то, что есть.

Comment: Тогда вариата два: 1. Передавать ответ от soap на сервер через ajax, там его обрабатывать razor/c# и в ответ возвращать html. 2. Делать запрос к soap на сервере, обрабатывать razor/c# и возвращать html на клиента.

Comment: Схема такая: страница делает запрос через скрипт к службе, отсылая SOAP-данные. Служба возвращает ответ тоже в виде SOAP в скрипт. После получения результата производится парсинг SOAP в коде C#. И данные в нужной форме выводятся на странице через код Razor. Как вернуть уже готовый вид страницы с веб-сервера не очень понимаю.

Comment: Вернуть может через ajax запрос к методу контроллера

Comment: $.post() подойдёт?

Comment: Да. Тут посмотрите http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/41828/JQuery-AJAX-with-ASP-NET-MVC

Comment: Могу ли я получить доступ к ответу от службы средствами .NET?

Comment: Можно так http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4791794/client-to-send-soap-request-and-received-response

Comment: Вот другой вариант работы - создается прокси класс http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ooxn5QCHXCw

Comment: Попробовал использовать HttpWebResponse. Судя по всему, код не срабатывает тогда, когда нужно. JQuery-скрипт срабатывает по клику.